# How to consume sunlight while programming in a cave?

Tags: development-environment

I work in a dungeon/cave. It is the basement. The atmosphere is great but I do miss sunlight. What do you do in such an environment? I found some devices that produces artificial sunlight but I think they can cause much problem.

Ideas?

Comment: This is not programming related; the question applies just as much to Milton from Office Space when he is moved to the basement. That said, take frequent breaks outside and consider taking vitamin D supplements.

Comment: I hear if use MongoDB enough, your computer will start to glow. :)

Comment: I feel you, quit your job, change employer. And make sure you ask for a ridiculously huge raise before you quit.

Comment: Yellowface burns us!  Must stay in the cave to code the Precious....

Comment: You buy yourself a laptop, a wifi access point and IT's silence and you work from the parking lot.

Comment: @Vlad If only that was so easy. I ask this question everyday that why I cannot work remotely!

Answer (score 0):

What problems are you having?  I know there are light sources that are used to treat seasonal affective disorder; they're not cheap, but might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I am not having any problems. I think I would love to sit in my beautiful backyard and do my job from there. Anyway, that is a completely different issue!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a opportunity to connect some servos with some mirrors :)  Fun coding project!